# How can I apply localStorage to input checkbox?

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox, local-storage

Note: I'm using vanilla js only.

I currently have a working script to add/remove classes via `select options` as well `localStorage`. All works great, [see jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/strawberrytittymilk/m1sfvzeL/).

Now, I'm wanting to add two `checkbox's` to perform in the same way. My problem is I'm not sure how to add checkboxes to my current `localStorage` script.

Here are my `checkbox's`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" onchange="checkbox1(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" onchange="checkbox2(this)">
```

And add/remove class on check/uncheck for checkbox1:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
checkbox.addEventListener("change", checkbox1, false);

function checkbox1() {
    var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
    if (isChecked) {
        [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body,.nc,.tags'), function(el) {
            el.classList.add('classname');
        });
    } else {
        [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('body,.nc,.tags'), function(el) {
            el.classList.remove('classname');
        });

    }
}
```

Works fine. Now I just need to add it to `localStorage`.

Here's my `localStorage` script that works for my `select options` (full example in my jsfiddle). How do I modify it to work for my `checkbox's` as well? I'm assuming I have to modify the second line to check for `checkbox` instead of `options` but I'm not sure how.

```
function selectTest(element) {
  const a = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
  setTest(a);
  localStorage['test'] = a;
}


function setTest(a) {
  if (a == "option1") {

    //add+remove classes here 

  }
}

(function() {

  if (localStorage['test'])
    document.getElementById("test").value = localStorage['test'];
  setTest(localStorage['test'])

})();
```

Comment: Can both the checkboxes be selected at the same time. What will happen in that case? Should it be red or blue

Comment: @Ghost Both checkboxes are styling different things, they are adding/removing classes to different elements. So yes, they can both be checked at the same time. I've already written this part, what I am trying to do is apply `localStorage` to them. Upon refresh, I want the browser to remember if the checkboxes were checked, and if so to add the classes.

Comment: Got it .. so I would suggest you to store an array in localStorage since multiple values can be checked. I will create a fiddle for it

Comment: Here it is. I have not set the color but you can see that values are preserved. Let me know if that works for you so I can add that as an answer https://jsfiddle.net/qctn08ym/44/

Comment: @Ghost Thank you for your help. Your code is working in that the checkbox remains checked upon refreshing, however the classes do not remain

Comment: Hi, I haven't added the classes. You can just write the function in the same loop to add the classes. I will update my code

Comment: Hey @strawberrymilk here is the link with the classes https://jsfiddle.net/8ufbzrn9/4/ Please accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: @Ghost Yes all is working great, thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it!!

Comment: @Ghost  Hello, sorry to bother again. I've noticed that the classes remaining on refresh only work for tags and id's, but not class elements. I've adjusted the first half your code for add and remove to work on classes, but I'm not sure how to modify your code after `function checkOnLocalStorage() {`

Comment: Can you send your jsfiddle and I will fix it :)

Comment: @Ghost Thanks so much [jsfiddle.net/hnyvw6r0/4](https://jsfiddle.net/strawberrytittymilk/hnyvw6r0/4/). Just to clarify, I have a mixture of elements I want to apply .option2 to. (tags, id's and classes)

Comment: @Ghost Commenting again to let you know (and anyone else who may read this) that your code is working perfectly, including class elements, I just had to move the localStorage part of the code to the bottom of my page, before ```</body>```. My mistake. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JS Fiddle if you just directly want to see the code https://jsfiddle.net/qctn08ym/44/

The idea is that since multiple checkboxes can be ticked and we need to preserve that we can store it as an array. Note that you can only store string in localStorage so you would need to convert the array to string and vice versa.

On any checkbox value changed we can call the function below that will set the localstorage

```
function checkboxChanged(e) {
  //Get the id of all checked checkboxes and store them as array
  // You can do this in loop as well by setting common class on checkboxes
  var c = []
    if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked) {
    c.push('checkbox1');
  }
  if(document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked) {
    c.push('checkbox2');
  }

  localStorage['test'] = c.toString();
}
```

Then you can just call the function below on document load

```
function checkOnLocalStorage() {
  if(!localStorage['test']) return;
  var checked = localStorage['test'].split(',');
  checked.map((id) => {
    document.getElementById(id).checked=true;
  })
}
```